# Python Weights Biases

Tags: python, python-3.x

import numpy as np
inprint_data = np.array ([0.5, 0.8])

weights = np.array ([0.1, 0.6])

#Calculate Node 0 value

node_0_input =(inprint_data + weights).sum() + biases

activation = 1.0 /( 1.0 + np.exp(-node_0_input))

print(activation)

The problem is
6 #Calculate Node 0 value
7
----> 8 node_0_input =(inprint_data + weights).sum() + biases
9
10 activation = 1.0 /( 1.0 + np.exp(-node_0_input))

NameError: name 'biases' is not defined

Any idea that can help me?

I tried to change to bias then change input_data to inprint_data but still not working

Comment: It appears your variable `biases` has not yet been defined, so you need to define it/create it as a variable

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make my own artificial neuron with own inputs, weights and biases